# Program stops on large inputs

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to do matrix multiplication using pointers in C++ but for large inputs the program stops executing. Without giving any error. If someone knows the solution of this then tell me.

Following is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int r1,c1,r2,c2;//variables

    cin>>r1;    
    cin>>c1;
    cin>>r2;
    cin>>c2;

    int **a, **b,**c;
    int sum=0;

    if (c1 == r2){
        a = new int *[c1]; //1st array
        b = new int *[c2]; //2nd array

        for (int i =0; i<=c1 ; i++ ){
            a[i] = new int [r1];
        } //constructing array

        for (int i =0; i<=c2 ; i++ ){
            b[i] = new int [r2];
        }//constructing array

        //input for 1st matrix
        for(int j=0; j<r1; j++){
            for(int k=0; k<c1; k++){
                cin>>a[j][k];
            }
        } 

        //input for 1st matrix
        for(int j=0; j<r2; j++){
            for(int k=0; k<c2; k++){
                    cin>>b[j][k];
                }
        }
        cout<<endl;

        //matrix multiplication
        for(int i=0;i<r1;i++){  
            for(int j=0;j<c2;j++){
                sum =0;
                for(int k=0; k<r1;k++){
                sum+= a[i][k]*b[k][j]; //matrix multiplication
                }
                cout<<sum<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Please enter feaseble values";
    }
    // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

**INPUT:**

```
> 4 5
> 5 2
> 1 2 3 4 5
> 6 7 8 9 10
> -10 -9 -8 -7 -6
> -5 -4 -3 -2 -1
> 1 2
> 3 4
> 5 5
> 4 3 //the code stops here and doesn't take any further inputs
> 2 1
```

Comment: It's probably an out of bounds access somewhere such as `a[i][k]` with invalid `i`or `k` indexes. BTW you should use correct variable names and not i,j,k,a1,a2, etc. Il will make your code more readable.

Comment: And did you try to debug it ?

Comment: Did you try to debug your application?

Comment: First problem: Your initialization of a and b is wrong. The loops should be 
`for (int i = 0; i < c1; i++) {` and `for (int i = 0; i < c2; i++) {` instead of using `<=`

Comment: Whats the solution to this ?

Comment: I have found one more problem with your code, about the way you multiply the elements. I have updated my answer, and I am notifying you here in case you miss it.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining your arrays backwards.  When you create a dynamic 2d array you do it with the form of

```
int** ary = new int*[rowCount];
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    ary[i] = new int[colCount];
```

Where you are doing

```
int** ary = new int*[colCount];
for(int i = 0; i < colCount; ++i)
    ary[i] = new int[rowCount];
```

I would suggest you use a 2d [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and let the vector handle all of the allocation for you.  to create a 2d vector you can do

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrixA(rowCount, std::vector<int>(colCount));
```

Comment: Although this is probably a homework assignment I agree with the last part of your answer (even with the `>` and `)` missing :).

Comment: As we are speaking c++ here, the best solution would definitely be to use `std::vector`.

Comment: @FlorisVelleman fixed the typo.  thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You're not being consistent in dealing with the rows and columns, according to the way you initialize the matrices, you should have:

```
a[col][row]
```

However, you are treating them later in the cin as:

```
a[row][col]
```

So just make up your mind on which should be the first dimension and which should be the second and fix accordingly, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have mistakenly swapped the values of `r` and `c` when assigning memory to `a` and `b`.

Correct code snippet should be

```
a = new int *[r1]; //1st array
b = new int *[r2]; //2nd array

for (int i =0; i<=r1 ; i++ ){
    a[i] = new int [c1];
} //constructing array

for (int i =0; i<=r2 ; i++ ){
    b[i] = new int [c2];
}//constructing array
```

Comment: @coderbca If you had used correct variables names, you would have found out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing arrays beyond their size, because the exit condition in some for loops is `<=`, but it should be `<`:

```
a = new int *[c1]; //1st array
b = new int *[c2]; //2nd array

for (int i =0; i<=c1 ; i++ ){ // Here you should have i<c1
    a[i] = new int [r1];
} //constructing array

for (int i =0; i<=c2 ; i++ ){ // Here you should have i<c2
    b[i] = new int [r2];
}//constructing array
```

Moreover, when you create the matrix you are following the wrong order. You should create the rows first, and then the columns. You are doing it the other way around, which results in indices going off. Try swapping rows and columns like this:

```
a = new int *[r1]; //1st array
b = new int *[r2]; //2nd array

for (int i =0; i<r1 ; i++ ){
    a[i] = new int [c1];
} //constructing array

for (int i =0; i<r2 ; i++ ){
    b[i] = new int [c2];
}//constructing array
```

I can compile this, and I get the result

```
  38    37  
 103   107  
-105  -117  
 -40   -47
```

### EDIT:

I have checked this result, out of curiosity, and it's wrong. The correct one should be:

```
  48    42
 123   117
-117  -123
 -42   -48
```

The error is that when you are multiplying the elements you are working with `r1` of them, but they are actually `c1`. So to fix the error you must change the exit condition of the for loop that uses k, from `for(int k=0; k<r1;k++){` to `for(int k=0; k<c1;k++){`